# Как убрать presense у бота? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript

Допустим сначала было прописано:

```
  client.user.setPresence({   
    game: {   
        name: '123',   
        type: "listening"    
    }   
 });
```

Затем я хочу убрать полностью статус у бота. Как это сделать?
Пробовал:

```
client.user.setPresence()
client.user.setPresence({status:dnd})   
client.user.setPresence(null)
```

Не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод `setActivity`

```js
client.user.setActivity(null)
```